# Search committee and Dean asked for my slides

Tags: job-search, interview, presentation, video-conference

I had a campus interview for an academic position. The day went well (in my view) and my talk generated lot of questions and discussion. I could say that since my answers were received in affirmative and I was also asked questions on the lines of how can you improve the teaching of so-and-so course, attract more students to take this so-and-so graduate course. Since about only 1/3 of the faculty members in that department attended the talk (total attendance might have been about ~25 persons), I was asked to send my slides to be circulated. When I spoke with a few faculty members after the day of the interview via zoom, they confirmed that they had indeed seen my slides that were emailed around. I had my meeting with the Dean separately a few days later via zoom (he wasn't available when I visited). We had a great meeting and the Dean commended my preparation and again asked for my slides (I made a set of ~12 slides specifically for the Dean that covered essential aspects of my candidacy from an administrator's point of view).

Overall, my research talk and one-on-one meetings with faculty members, search committee members, and the Head of that department went well and many expressed positive remarks about my potential fit with their department.

How should interpret their circulating my slides with the faculty?
Does that happen often?
Can I take their promptness in doing so as a positive sign?
Can I interpret the Dean asking for a copy of my slides as a positive thing?

Comment: Follow up question" "is it a bad sign for my faculty career that my SE question got closed straight away?"

Comment: What is "SE question" mean? Salary Expectations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Can I take their promptness in doing so as a positive sign? Can I interpret the Dean asking for a copy of my slides as a positive thing?" -- You can never know. They may have done the same for all of the other candidates. Or the dean might actually be interested in the topic and wanted to learn something about it. Or ...

In other words, don't spend your time reading tea leaves. You can't know whether it's a good or bad sign, or no sign at all. Put your efforts in the things you *can* control: Like writing your next paper.

Comment: +1 good answer. I'd be a little kinder: it's certainly not a negative sign.

Comment: Correct. It's not a negative sign. But I also don't think it's a positive sign. It's entirely unknowable.

Comment: +1 don't spend your time reading tea leaves (it could be a dead or alive Schrödinger's cat). #efforts: writing your next paper, grant proposal...